# Why does Internet Explorer give me pop-ups while using Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, troubleshooting, popups

When I'm browsing with Firefox, I often get pop-ups from Internet Explorer. How is this possible?

When I then start Internet Explorer, I get a message that I have arrived on an incorrect homepage.

How do I correct this behavior?

Comment: Welkom op Super User! De voertaal op deze website is Engels, ik heb jouw vraag voor jou vertaald. Gelieve in het vervolg Engels te gebruiken, zodat iedereen jou kan helpen en er ook baat aan kan hebben. Veel succes met een oplossing te zoeken...

Comment: This question was initially closed because it was in a foreign language, but was edited shortly afterwards.  It should be reopened.